# Change lgbm internal parameter (threshold) by hand

Tags: lightgbm

I have trained a model with lgbm. I can dump its interval values with

```
booster.dump_model()
```

and see all the internal parameters that has been optimized during the training (leaf values, threshold, index of the variables for each split, ...). For testing purpose I would like to change some. Is there a way? I guess that changing just the output of `dump_model` will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your model to a human-understandable format using 
`booster.save_model('model.txt')`, do your modifications on `model.txt`, and load back the modified model using `modified_booster = lightgbm.Booster(model_file='model.txt')`.
I hope it helps!

Comment: right, I thought about that solution, but... I would like to do it with the python api

Comment: this is done using python. Can you please rephrase if I misunderstood :) ? thanks!

Comment: Changing the txt file is not done by the lgbm python api. You save the txt with lgbm python api, you load it with the lgbm python api, but the editing is done by hand, without. I want something like `booster.tree(1234).node(321).threshold = 999`

Comment: You need a parser for this. take a look at https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/31